# SVG scale to container, and crop overflow, on IE

Tags: svg

I need such an inline SVG:

1) it scales to container width,

2) height proportionally scales,

3) elements outside of viewbox(?) are cropped.

---

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoobxG?editors=1100)

All three points are satisfied on Chrome.  But not ok on IE.

---

Point 1) above, for IE to scale I have put `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`

2) If I put `svg { height: 100%; }`, ok on Chrome, not ok on IE (it should be a square).
Not putting this, IE ok, but Chrome not ok.
**What can I do?**

3) **Not cropped on IE**.  I want a half circle in the bottom, as in Chrome.  This thing may rotate so I don't want to draw a half circle by `<path>`.
`svg { overflow: hidden; }` is ok only when there is no `slice` in `preserveAspectRatio`, that is, no scaling.  But I need scaling.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jyyxoz?editors=1100

Comment: If you don't like the linked solution, then the alternative is to specify an exact width and height for the SVG.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau  The linked solution solves the cropping issue but the SVG does not scale at all to the container on Chrome and IE.  The SVG is 300 wide.

Comment: Then just remove the `width="300" height="300"` from the `<svg>` element.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau  Then it is like my initial demo, ok on Chrome, height wrong on IE.  [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvaNwa?editors=1100)

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my Codepen, the `width` and `height` values in the `<canvas>` were wrong. I have fixed it now.

Comment: [This](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvXqpr?editors=1100) needs no `<canvas>`, with the use of `clip-path`, and `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"` instead of `xMidYMid`